# How to avoid "Interrupted while waiting on semaphore" exception in the servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, servlets, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a byte array content on **Google Drive**.
For this,I initialised **Drive** class in a jsp. Then, I put the Drive's object to the a class **Processer** for further processing. This class downloads a file in byte array and uploads it to the Google Drive.
But, it is showing exception at:

```
service.files().insert(body, new ByteArrayContent("application/vnd.google-app.file", bytes)).execute();
```

The Exception stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Interrupted while waiting on semaphore:
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.makeAsyncCall(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:188)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:151)
at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:120)
at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:38)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.fetchResponse(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:417)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.getInputStream(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:296)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.getResponseCode(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:149)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:36)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:94)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequestWithoutGZip(MediaHttpUploader.java:545)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequest(MediaHttpUploader.java:562)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeUploadInitiation(MediaHttpUploader.java:519)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.resumableUpload(MediaHttpUploader.java:384)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:336)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:418)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
at com.rapps.splitingtool.Processer.run(Processer.java:135)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.RequestThreadFactory$1$1$2.run(RequestThreadFactory.java:110)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.RequestThreadFactory$1$1.run(RequestThreadFactory.java:107)

Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1301)
at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:317)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.makeAsyncCall(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:185)
... 21 more
```

Please help me. I am confused.

**Thank you for help!**

Comment: Is the appengine transaction timing out? Log a timestamp for the files.insert and the exception.

Comment: May you please explain me how to do it?

Comment: What should I do if it is timing out?

Comment: if the file is too large it mught be taking too long to process and GAE might be shutting you down (DEadelineExceededException) which might be wrapped by this exception you see here, is it possible file processing is going over 60 seconds?